# restrict removing of Elements while iterating

Tags: java, list, concurrency, iterator

I have a Class that hols a static List of Listeners, like this:

```
public class StaticFoo{

    public static interface ActionInterface{
        void onAction();
    }

    private static ArrayList<ActionInterface> sList = new ArrayList();

    public static ArrayList<ActionInterface> getList(){
        return sList;
    }

    public static void addAction(ActionInterface action){
        sList.add(action);
    }

    public static boolean removeAction(ActionInterface action){
        return sList.remove(action);
    }

}
```

My Problem is now: If I'm iterating over this list and call the `onAction` method of that interface, how to prevent that one of those Listeners is calling `StaticFoo.removeAction(this)`, which will trigger a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `ArrayList` to hold the listeners.

It avoids the concurrency bottleneck on read-only operations such as `get` and `contains`, but it does this by doing a lot more work in mutating operations, and by modifying the visibility rules. Furthermore, the mutating operations lock the entire list, and are therefore a concurrency bottleneck.

Comment: An alternative is to iterate over a copy of the `ArrayList` using `toArray`